# Add arrow key navigation to site with variable in page

Tags: javascript, navigation, navigationbar

I would like to add this code to allow navigation through a website with left and right arrows.  Is there any way to assign the window.location variable from an image that is linked on that page?  I'm trying to make the left and right arrows on the page that are used for navigation on the page to be assigned to the left and right arrows on the keyboard.

```
img src="leftarrow.png" = previous page
img src="rightarrow.png" = next page
```

Code to be used: (other code is fine too)

```
var browser = navigator.appName;
if (browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
    document.onkeydown=keydownie;
} else {
    document.onkeydown=keydown;
}
function keydownie(e) {
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    if (e.keyCode) {
        keycode = e.keyCode;
        if ((keycode == 39) || (keycode == 37)) {
            window.event.keyCode = 0;
        }
    } else {
        keycode = e.which;
    }
    if (keycode == 37) {
        window.location = '!!PREVIOUS_URLHERE!!';
        return false;
    } else if (keycode == 39){
        window.location = '!!NEXT_URLHERE!!';
        return false;
    }
}
function keydown(e) {
    if (e.which) {
        keycode = e.which;
    } else {
        keycode = e.keyCode;
    }
    if (keycode == 37) {
        window.location = '!!PREVIOUS_URLHERE!!';
        return false;
    } else if (keycode == 39) {
        window.location = '!!NEXT_URLHERE!!';
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the image is wrapped in an anchor tag (otherwise how would it work?), you could do something like this:

```
if (keycode == 37) {
    img = document.querySelector("img[src='leftarrow.png']");
    window.location = img.parentElement.href;
    return false;
} else if (keycode == 39) {
    img = document.querySelector("img[src='rightarrow.png']");
    window.location = img.parentElement.href;
    return false;
}
```

We're looking for the appropriate image/navigation link and getting the url from it's anchor container.

Comment: Yes it is wrapped in an anchor tag.  Will give that a try thanks.

Comment: Jaime.  Would you be able to simplify your answer by placing the information in the code above?  I searched everywhere on how to get that to work with no luck.  Thanks.

Comment: Just added a snippet of your code with the solution implemented.